# Adjusting points in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

I'm new to Smalltalk, so please bear with me.  I'm simply trying to make a simple drawing using Morphs.

Now I can create Circles and Lines, but I'm having issues adjusting the start and end point in my workspace.

If you can offer any advice I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
man := Morph new.
head := CircleMorph new color: Color blue.
body := LineMorph new.
man addMorph: head.
man addMorph:  body.
man openInWindow.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verticesAt:put:` allows you to directly change the points in a `LineMorph`:

```
line := LineMorph new.
line verticesAt: 1 put: 0@0.
line verticesAt: 2 put: 100@50.
```

or use the `#vertices:color:borderWidth:borderColor:` class-side method:

```
LineMorph 
    vertices: (Array with: 0@0 with: 100@50)
    color: Color transparent
    borderWidth: 1
    borderColor: Color black
```